# Meaning of layoutopt tool output

Tags: android, layout, layout-optimization

I use layoutopt like 'layoutopt layout.xml'

And I get this message:

```
9:18 This tag and its children can be replaced by one <TextView/> and a compound drawable
28:78 Use an android:layout_height of 0dip instead of wrap_content for better performance
```

But I do not understand the meaning, can someone clarify me the meaning of it

use 0dip on what? on the layout? I want my layout to wrap the content not to be zero size height

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0px"
   android:layout_alignParentTop="true" android:background="#30000000"
   android:padding="5dip">

   <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView1"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="@drawable/bzz_icon"></ImageView>

   <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/textView1"
      android:textColor="#FFFFFF" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_gravity="center" android:gravity="left"
      android:layout_marginLeft="15dip" android:text="@string/title"
      android:textSize="20sp"></TextView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Please post your layout XML as well.

Comment: Please post your layout.xml. It is difficult to determine the cause of an error / warning unless we can see the source.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first message is saying that you can replace your `linearLayout3` with only a `TextView` and use `android:drawableLeft` instead of the `ImageView`.

The second message is probably telling you that on whatever is at line `28` of your layout you can use `layout_height` of `0dp` instead of `wrap_content`. This is usually used in conjunction with `layout_weight` when your element will be expanded anyway. However, this is just a guess and you should post your entire layout XML, including line 28, so that we can better figure out the meaning of the message.

Comment: <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_marginLeft="10dip" android:layout_height="0px"
   android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_weight="1"
   android:focusableInTouchMode="true" android:fillViewport="true">
   <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout4" ...

Comment: It is a ScrollView, I didn't know that if you set 0px will wrap anyway

Comment: @user706780 it is expanded because you have set `layout_weight="1"`, which tells the parent view (probably a `LinearLayout`) to give that view all the available space that is left after measuring and laying out the other views in the layout. You might want to read this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout

Answer (score 0):

```
TextView with the left image and the text is centered

  <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center|left"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:text="@string/hello" />
```